# Reverse proxy badly generated xsd paths

Tags: jakarta-ee, xsd, proxy, weblogic, reverse-proxy

I need to deploy a proxy application in a WebLogic server through which users access a SOAP web service that is running in another server.

The original web sevice is exposed in server A example htttp://serverA/serviceA.

And I need to expose this service through the proxy in the WebLogic server as https://proxyServer/operationA

I have tried with (PathTrim and PathPerpend) in my web.xml file and deploying the proxy app as /operationA.

```
<web-app>
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.proxy.HttpProxyServlet</servlet-class>

     <init-param>
     <param-name>redirectURL</param-name>
     <param-value>http://serverA/</param-value>
     </init-param>

     <init param>
     <param-name>PathTrim</param-name>
     <param-value>/operationA</param-value>
     </init-param>         

     <init-param>
     <param-name>PathPrepend</param-name>
     <param-value>serviceA</param-value>
     </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Doing this I'm able to access the service's wsdl through the proxy but the xsd schemas URLS are wrongly formed and therefore can´t be downloaded by the clients.

In this example, the wsdl says that the location of the schema is :

schemaLocation="http://proxyServer/serviceA?xsd=1"
**and it should say:**
schemaLocation="http://proxyServer/operationA?xsd=1"

Can anyone help me? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Are you talking about inline content? If inline content that references the "old" URL needs to be changed on the fly, you're going to need much more than just a proxy.

Comment: Thanks @Necreaux. No i'm not refering to the inline content. I mean, I can use the webservice correctly from the proxy but when I see the wsdl the schemas paths are wrongly formed and therefore a dynamic client will fail

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need. This makes any redirection done in the application server to be sent to the specified URL and I need this to be done only with the requests that corresponds with the proxy application.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Login to your weblogic admin console
- Navigate to `Servers -> <server name> -> Protocols -> HTTP settings`
- Edit the `Frontend Host` to be the location you want. The Frontend Host is the name of the host to which all redirected URLs will be sent.

This should update the values you see in the WSDL for schema location.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need. This makes any redirection done in the application server to be sent to the specified URL and I need this to be done only with the requests that corresponds with the proxy application. Thnks